# Problemas con password_verify en php. No compara contraseñas

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, php7

comunidad.

Estoy realizando un login con jquery, ajax, php y mysql

Al registrar al usuario, uso la función `password_hash` que viene por defecto con php y me registra a la perfección. me encripta la contraseña. El problema está cuando intento logearme con esa misma contraseña.

Para intentar logearme, uso la función `password_verify` que también viene con php, para comparar la contraseña que está enviando el usuario mediante el formulario con la que está en la base de datos. El problema es que me devuelve un "false" aunque la contraseña sea correcta.

Aquí les dejo el código:

Código de Registro

signup.php

```
class Signup extends Controller {

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function render() {
            $this->view->render('signup/signup');       
        }   

        public function signup(){
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                header('content-Type: application/json');

                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                $options = ['memory_cost' => 1<<10, 'time_cost' => 4, 'threads' => 2];
                $protpass = password_hash('$pass', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);

                if ($this->model->insert(["name" => $name, "lastName" => $lastName, "email" => $email, "protpass" => $protpass])) {

                    echo json_encode('true');
                } else {
                    echo json_encode('false');
                }

            }
        }           

    }
```

signupmodel.php

```
class SignupModel extends Model {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function insert($datos){

            try {
                $email = $datos['email'];

                $query = $this->db->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
                $query->execute();
                $fila = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if ($fila == 0) {
                    $insert = $this->db->connect()->prepare('INSERT INTO user (name, lastName, email, pass) VALUES (:name, :lastName, :email, :pass)');
                    $insert->execute([
                        'name' => $datos['name'],
                        'lastName' => $datos['lastName'],
                        'email' => $datos['email'],
                        'pass' => $datos['protpass']
                    ]);
                    // return $insert;
                    return true;
                } 
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                // return false;
                echo $e->getLine();
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

A partir de aquí, código de login

login.html

```
<form class="form-signin" id="myFormulario">
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Login</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="emial">Email address</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="log">Sign in</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">&copy; 2017-2019</p>
</form>
```

login.php //este es mi controlador, donde realizo algunas validaciones antes de hacer la consulta a la base de datos

```
class Login extends Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function render(){
            $this->view->render('login/login');
        }

        public function login(){

            if (!empty($_POST['email']) and !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    header('content-Type: application/json');

                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $pass  = $_POST['pass'];

                    if ($this->model->getUser(["email" => $email, "pass" => $pass])) {

                    } 
                }
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
```

loginmodel.php //aquí realizo la consulta a la base de datos y compruebo el email y el password

```
class LoginModel extends Model {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getUser($data){

            try {

                $pass = $data['pass'];
                $json = array();

                $query = $this->db->connect()->prepare("SELECT name, lastName, email, pass FROM user WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
                $query->execute(['email' => $data['email']]);
                $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $pass2 = password_verify($pass, $row['pass']);

                echo json_encode($pass2);           

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $e->getLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

De antemano, muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Comment: Estaras guardando mal tu pass? podrias poner la funcion que lo guarda?

Comment: @gbianchi ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Esto no está bien: `$protpass = password_hash('$pass', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);` ahí le estás pasando siempre el valor `$pass`, no el dato que hay en la variable. Debes ponerlo así: **`$protpass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);`** sin las comillas simples. Si haces esta prueba: `$pass="prueba"; echo '$pass';` verás que en pantalla se imprime la palabra `$pass` y no la palabra `prueba`.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias ... si es eso...

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problemas con las comillas.

```
$protpass = password_hash('$pass', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Debe de quedar asi:

```
$protpass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

[Si quieres leer un poco mas acerca de las diferencias entre comillas sencilla y doble lee esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)